# MPI cluster with different operating systems

Tags: mpi, distributed-computing, mpich

I want to run my MPI program on two machines, one with ubuntu 18.04 and the other with Windows 10. Is it possible to form a cluster with different operating systems? (I'm using MPICH)

If possible, how?? I could not find any resources online.

Comment: Yes, it is possible in general. You can even run MPI programs on combinations of different CPU architectures. All you need is an MPI implementation that was compiled with support for heterogeneous environments. In your case, you need to have the same version of MPICH on both Linux and Windows, and a way to launch the executables. You may find [this](http://hex.ro/wp/blog/running-mpich2-between-windows-7-and-ubuntu-10-4/) helpful.

Comment: @HristoIliev Thank you so much. I'll try this option and will give an update

Answer (score 2):

You should have the same version of MPI installed on different distributions. In such case, it is possible to use MPICH2 with Linux and Windows machines simultaneously.

But, it should be noted that performance characteristics of the machine plays a significant role as the application performance will be limited by the slowest processor and hence it is not recommended to execute MPI jobs across machines with different performance characteristics. Also, it should be noted that even if the hardware is identical, the performance of MPI will be different between MPICH2 on Linux and Windows.

Kindly note that the last version of MPICH supported on Windows was MPICH2 1.4.1p1. MPICH is not supported on Windows anymore including Cygwin as conveyed in [MPICH FAQ](https://wiki.mpich.org/mpich/index.php/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Q:_Why_can.27t_I_build_MPICH_on_Windows_anymore.3F).